# Zoom button above the plot window in R-studio doesn´t work

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, zooming

I´m trying to zoom the plot that I have got in R-studio but when I press the button "zoom" above the plot window (that should show the graph in a bigger window) the new window which pops up is blank.

Probably it is something easy but I can't find any solution.
[image]

The Session Info

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 
 
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.0.1     tidyr_1.1.3    
 [6] tibble_3.1.4    tidyverse_1.3.1 dplyr_1.0.7     ggthemr_1.1.0   scales_1.1.1   
[11] ggplot2_3.3.5   prophet_1.0     rlang_0.4.11    Rcpp_1.0.7     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.2           jsonlite_1.7.2       modelr_0.1.8         RcppParallel_5.1.4  
 [5] StanHeaders_2.21.0-7 assertthat_0.2.1     stats4_4.1.1         cellranger_1.1.0    
 [9] yaml_2.2.1           lattice_0.20-44      pillar_1.6.2         backports_1.2.1     
[13] glue_1.4.2           digest_0.6.27        rvest_1.0.1          colorspace_2.0-2    
[17] htmltools_0.5.2      dygraphs_1.1.1.6     pkgconfig_2.0.3      rstan_2.21.2        
[21] broom_0.7.9          haven_2.4.3          processx_3.5.2       tzdb_0.1.2          
[25] generics_0.1.0       farver_2.1.0         ellipsis_0.3.2       withr_2.4.2         
[29] cli_3.0.1            magrittr_2.0.1       crayon_1.4.1         readxl_1.3.1        
[33] ps_1.6.0             fs_1.5.0             fansi_0.5.0          anytime_0.3.9       
[37] xts_0.12.1           xml2_1.3.2           pkgbuild_1.2.0       tools_4.1.1         
[41] loo_2.4.1            prettyunits_1.1.1    hms_1.1.0            lifecycle_1.0.0     
[45] matrixStats_0.60.1   extraDistr_1.9.1     V8_3.4.2             neuralnet_1.44.2    
[49] munsell_0.5.0        reprex_2.0.1         callr_3.7.0          compiler_4.1.1      
[53] grid_4.1.1           rstudioapi_0.13      htmlwidgets_1.5.4    labeling_0.4.2      
[57] gtable_0.3.0         codetools_0.2-18     inline_0.3.19        DBI_1.1.1           
[61] curl_4.3.2           R6_2.5.1             zoo_1.8-9            gridExtra_2.3       
[65] lubridate_1.7.10     fastmap_1.1.0        utf8_1.2.2           stringi_1.7.4       
[69] parallel_4.1.1       vctrs_0.3.8          dbplyr_2.1.1         tidyselect_1.1.1
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Because I encountered exactly the same problem (RStudio 2021.09.1 Build 372).

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have wasted a lot of time finding a solution. I don't like having stupid problems like that and it's kind of annoying, but you can handle it somehow. Anyhow, it would be good to find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

While using two screens, with scripts opened on one monitor and main pain on the other, I was having the same problem. I hovered over the RStudio icon on my taskbar, hovered over the blank Plot Zoom window, right clicked my mouse, and clicked on Maximize and that worked (when there is only one plot in Plots window). It did not work when I was generating several plots.

But bringing all RStudio IDE windows into a same screen monitor, the Zoom button worked.

I hope this helps.